# Is there a function in Hive similar to the MySQL truncate FUNCTION?

Tags: hive

Not to truncate a table...In MySQL, I can use `truncate(123.328,2)` to get `123.32`.

But how to do this in `Hive`? I tried `select cast(123.328 as decimal(10,2));` but it returns `123.33`; also tried `floor()` but it only returns integer.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this hack, hope this helps you.

You Multiply the number by 100 times, drop the decimals by Cast/format to BIGINT
then divide the bigint by 100

```
select (CAST((123.328*100) AS BIGINT)/100);
```

Comment: Good idea! Thanks!